# array_search not finding all the values

Tags: php, arrays, search

```
Array
(
    [0] => 159042564114859_722842697734840
    [1] => 180466813056_10152147419628057
    [2] => 201613513237343_622449081153782
)


$post_ids = array('201613513237343_622449081153782', '180466813056_10152147419628057', '159042564114859_722842697734840');

foreach($posts->data as $post)
{
    if(array_search( $post->id, $post_ids ))
    {
        print '<p>FOUND ' . $post->id . '<p>';

    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
FOUND 159042564114859_722842697734840

FOUND 180466813056_10152147419628057
```

For some reason, it does not detect the third item in the array, with the index of 3, value of 201613513237343_622449081153782

This outputs:

```
foreach($posts->data as $post)
{
    print '<p>post->id: ' . $post->id . '</p>'; 
}

post->id: 159042564114859_722842697734840

post->id: 180466813056_10152147419628057

post->id: 201613513237343_622449081153782
```

So I know the data is in there, what am I doing wrong with the array_search function?

Comment: I've seen weird things like this happen when you aren't strict about ints & strings --- strange it would catch the first two, but perhaps it's worth a shot...

Comment: Here it is in action: https://eval.in/93022

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't output the *first* post id because `array_search` returns the `index`, which is `0`.

Change your check to:

```
if (array_search($post->id, $post_ids) !== false) {
```

to **explicitly** compare with `false`.

---

```
0 == false; // true
0 === false; // false
```

---

PHP is not very nice about it's arguments and return values, but most *search* functions use some kind of 'not found' value. `-1`, `false` and `null` are common values used for this purpose.